# Which of these declarations is invalid at the class level of a program

Tags: c#, class, object

I have an exam coming up and our lecturer has given us a sample exam and for some reason i can find within my own logic and search through notes, the answer to this multiple choice question in regards to C# programming language.

I've listed the question below. What is the answer?

**Which of these declarations is invalid at the class level of a program?**

```
(a) int iCount;
(b) double dPrice;
(c) private string sName;
(d) public boolean bMember;
```

Comment: Is the class specified?  For example, is it public or private class?

Comment: They are all valid _within_ a class. If your teacher means at the _same level_ as a class then all are invalid.

Comment: @DStanley I wondered about that.  Perhaps the question omits `(e) all of the above`

Comment: No that's the entire question. It seems very ambiguous, but I found another post and it mentioned that in c# that global variables are not used.

Comment: Within a class, those wouldn't be global.  Fear not!  @mybirthname noticed what the rest of us didn't.  `boolean` should be `bool` or `Boolean` as he's answered below.  Don't forget to upvote it and accept :)

Comment: If the catch is that d) should be `bool` or `Boolean` that's a terrible question.

Comment: @clarkitect hahaha didn't even think that. I think I've been studying for too long and I'm over thinking. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public boolean bMember;
```

This is invalid, it should be

```
public Boolean bMember;
```

Answer (score 1):

D is the invalid declarations. Beacuse in C# "boolean" does not a valid type name. the valid one should be 'Boolean'.

Comment: Why post the same answer as "mybirthname" ? Yours doesn't really add anything more ...

Comment: I just post what I know, and before I post I did not know that my post is same as jim. BTW I just filter the newest question, then post my answer, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is d. It should be "public bool bMember;"